# Oracle incremental query in a table with no ID or timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to regularly extract data from an Oracle 11 table using *sqlplus*. For example, I need every day to extract the new rows inserted into that table.

On a table with a primary key such as *RECORD_ID* (assuming it is inserted incrementally), that query would be:

```
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE RECORD_ID > &LAST_RECORD_ID_FROM_PREVIOUS_QUERY
```

On a table with a *RECORD_DATE* timestamp, this could similarly done like:

```
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE RECORD_DATE > &LAST_RECORD_DATE_FROM_PREVIOUS_QUERY
```

My question is: how do you do this when you have no timestamps and no incremental column you could use? Can this be achieved with *ROWID*?

Comment: rowid is an "address" for where the row is located, it does not "increment" and inserts/deletes may change the address or re-assign an address.

Comment: If you need to do this every day, then you need an identity column or insertion date/time.

Comment: It is preferable to add a date/timestamp column and default it to `sysdate/systimestamp`, your job will be much easier and adding an index or creating partitions on it will greatly improve data retrieval time.

Comment: Of course it'd be easy with an identity or timestamp. However the table cannot be modified, hence my question.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to enable flashback and then you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
MINUS
SELECT * FROM table_name AS OF TIMESTAMP SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not an option in my case but that's an approach I'd never thought about. I wonder how efficient that'd be on large tables (100m rows).

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected there isn't any easy solution. It has to be one of:

- Adding an identity or timestamp column
- Do a diff using flashback
- Add a trigger on insert on the table

Unfortunately none of which is practical in my environment. Case closed!